# Filtering values on Excel Pivot Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I'm importing data into Excel Pivot Chart from SQL Server. I'm trying to filter out Values (decimal type on SQL) below a certain threshold.
For this, I click PivotChart filter and see that filter may be applied on both Legend and the Axis. I click the drop down menu and see that both the Axis fields and Legend fields have Value Filter for Y applicable. I choose Legend Fields (inadvertently) and set the "Max of Y" "is greater than" 15. Data with value 7 still shows up. (Same is true if I apply the filter on Axis as well). How can I achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: I would build this into your SQL query (e.g. add a where value < x statement)-then Excel doesn't have to filter anything. Is there a reason that wouldn't work?

Comment: Thanks mate.kinda worked for me. I just wanted to make it from inside Excel for manageability purposes. btw, any idea about why date (axis) would lose its order after importing date. i.e. 27.02.2015 hh:mm  coming after 01.03.2015 hh:mm?

Comment: @dav: could you post the comment as an answer, so the question can be closed as having an answer?